# Why this link doesnt get the text-align:right?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7y6FQ/) code :

```
<div class="footer_bar_row_desc_richedi">
    <a class="myText" href="#">My Text</a>
    <div class="myDiv">
        &nbsp
    </div>   
</div>

.myText
{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;    
    color:#b90e1d;
    text-decoration:none;    
    float:left; 
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    text-align:right;
}

.myDiv
{
    float:right; 
    width:25px; 
    padding-right:5px; 
    text-align:right; 
    margin-bottom:3px; 
    background:red;
}
```

and I'd like to put the text on the link to the right, near (on the left) of the red div. Seems that attribute `text-align:right;` doesnt works. Any Idea?

Comment: as per your question the text-align:right is working . So, increase the link width & check yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your .mytext div a width. It is collapsing to the exact width of your text at the moment which means that right aligning the text looks as if it is doing nothing...

See

http://jsfiddle.net/hS3JA/

Answer (score 2):

by default the A tag has inline display style (fit container to contents size). you must set display:block; so the attributes width, height, text-align will affect the object

Comment: It doesnt work. In fact the red div will be moved to the bottom of the link. I want it stay to the same line.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<div class="footer_bar_row_desc_richedi">
    <div class="myDiv">
        &nbsp
    </div>   
    <a class="myText" href="#">My Text</a>
</div>

.myText
{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;    
    color:#b90e1d;
    text-decoration:none;    
    float:right; 
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    /*text-align:right;*/
}

.myDiv
{
    float:right; 
    width:25px; 
    padding-right:5px; 
    text-align:right; 
    margin-bottom:3px; 
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: LOL! But Where is the link? :)

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: right` will only align the text to the right inside its own element. Since `a` is an inline element, it never takes up more width than it needs, and `text-align` is rendered useless.

Try putting `display: inline-block` in `.myText { }` and give it a width.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by encapsulating it in paragraph tag...

```
<p style="text-align:right;">...link...</p>
```